# Sql in oracle to find out missing records from its distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am sorry , this one is not working... May be I should have clarified this earlier. The values A,B,C,D etc... Are the Distinct values for CODE in the Table. There are several hundreds of IDs in the table and each ID can have one to many Code values. In the above example assume that there are 5 distinct values of Code from table A. There are 3 IDs and each ID is associated in Table A as follows

ID    Code
1      A
1      B
1      C
2      D
2      A
3      B
3      C
4      A
4      B
4      C
4      D
4      E

As you see above there are several IDs associated with different Code values. I need the result as follows

ID   CODE
1     D
1     E
2     B
2     C
2     E
3     A
3     D
3     E

ID 4 should not return anything because it contain all possible Codes (in this case A,B,C,D,E)

Comment: Where does the list (A,B,C,D,E) come from?

Comment: So you have a master table which says which ID has how many codes assigned. If so please share it in your qustion as well

Comment: can you add some data and show how you try  on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

First you should take distinct values for both column in different sub-query, second cross join them - that will give you all possible combination,
finally exclude combination which are already presnet

```
select *
from 
(select distinct ID
from your_table) ytI, /* this sub-query will return all possible ID */
(select distinct code
from your_table) ytc /* this sub-query will return all possible code */
where (ytI.ID,ytc.Code) /* there will be cross-join as there are no join condition between first two tables*/
not in  /* exclude those records which are already present */
(select id,code
from your_table yt_i)
```

Comment: @srini please upvote/accept it as answer if it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select T2.ID, T1.missing_value
from
(
  select 'A' missing_value from dual UNION
  select 'B' from dual UNION
  select 'C' from dual UNION
  select 'D' from dual UNION
  select 'E' from dual
) T1,
(
  select distinct id from MYTABLE
) T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * FROM MYTABLE M WHERE M.CODE = T1.missing_value and M.ID = T2.ID
)
ORDER BY T2.ID, T1.missing_value
```